# Build OS-independent notepad with some code completion - appropriate platform?

Tags: programming-languages, gtk, wxwidgets, client-side

I want to build as simple notepad application with some code-completion.
It should be easy to compile to Linux, OS X and Windows.

I'm looking at wx-widgets or GTK. Others?? (as web-service as worst case.),
and without library dependencies.

Or does there exist any OS-independent FOSS editor with plug-in functionality.
(Eclipse way to heavy).

To be specific, what I want is a "helper" when coding XML towards an application-framework that use XML extensively. As libraries are loaded (through XML) new tags should be allowed and their existence should be prompted to user, both in toolbar (tags) and auto-complete (attributes).

Recommendations?

regards,

//t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [XML Copy Editor](http://xml-copy-editor.sourceforge.net/): I've used it and it's not the best editor, but it does do the autocompletion.
- [Conglomerate](http://www.conglomerate.org/): Looks quite promising but I never got it to work when I tried it out a year ago. Perhaps it's improved since then.

As for an OS-independent FOSS editor with plugin functionality that is more lightweight than Eclipse, try [Gedit](http://projects.gnome.org/gedit/). It's not too difficult to write plugins for whatever functionality you may need. It's based on GTK.